# Where to add debugging points in a code

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, mfc

if we got a huge project consisting of many files and each files has more than 2k lines, i want to see what code is behind initialization of pop-up menu, code is not properly documented, any proper technique for these other then hit and trial or many debuggings points, the application is MFC based

Comment: Do you want to know how items are enabled and disabled or do you want to know how context menus are created?

Comment: i want to disable a particular option it has in tools->preferences->desiredoption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Determine the ID or this menu item in the resource file.

You will find an ON_UPDATE_COMMAND handler, that specifies the routine that is responsible to enable or disable the item.

Comment: What should I tell you about ON_UPDATE_COMMAND handler that is not in any standard MFC tutorial and the MSDN docs. http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/b8c866kb(v=vs.90).aspx